# How to compute with Mathematica the space representation of a group for a given point set?

Tags: group-theory

A set of points $P = \{p_1,p_2,\dots\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ in 3D is given. A symmetry transformation $S \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ is considered here as a matrix which maps the elements of $P$ to a set $P' = SP = \{Sp_1,Sp_2,\dots\}$ such that $P=P'$ holds in the sense of sets, i.e., $P\setminus P' = \emptyset$. The set of all symmetry transformations is referred here as the point group $G = \{S_1,S_2,\dots\}$ of the given point set $P$.

**For given point set $P$, how would you compute $G$ in Mathematica?**

I know that for several point sets, group theory data is available and you can get the group matrices $S_i \in G$ if you know the name for the corresponding group. But I am interested on a way to get the matrices $S_i$ with Mathematica in the case I do not know the name of the corresponding group.

**Explicit example:** consider the 8 corners of a cube centered at the origin

```
P = {
   {0, 0, 0}
   , {1, 0, 0}
   , {0, 1, 0}
   , {0, 0, 1}
   , {1, 1, 0}
   , {1, 0, 1}
   , {0, 1, 1}
   , {1, 1, 1}
   };
P = P - 1/2;
Graphics3D[{PointSize -> Medium, Point@P}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

For this case I know that the octahedral group $O_h$ containing 48 symmetry matrices fulfills what I want, i.e.,

```
G = FiniteGroupData[{"CrystallographicPointGroup", 32}, "SpaceRepresentation"];
Dimensions@G
check = And @@ (Complement[P.#, P] == {} & /@ G)
```

> {48,3,3}
>
> True

But I have no real idea on how to get these symmetry matrices just starting from a point set for which I have no intuition for. I do not know how to use `Complement` in `Solve`. I have been playing around with `Sort` in order to define some order on the set of points but, of course, that does not help in general, since you can then get only a solution for special cases.

```
S = Array[s, {3, 3}];
S /. First@Solve[Sort[P.S] == Sort[P]]
```

> {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}

How would you tackle the problem with Mathematica? Thanks!

Comment: This is an especially important problem in chemistry, when one wants to determine the point group of a molecule. Some approaches are in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.22995) and [this article](https://doi.org/10.1021/ci990322q).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the literature references. I will take a look at them.